# Generating Big5 characters in powershell

Tags: powershell, encoding, character-encoding

I want to create big5-encoded Chinese characters and save them into a txt file with powershell.

I know that in windows `cmd.exe`, I can easily create big5 characters with something like this:

```
echo 信 > testBig5.txt
```

However, in the above command creates Chinese characters encoded in UTF-16LE in powershell.

I use a binary editor(e.g. *UltraEdit*, *Notepad++'s HEX-Editor plugin*) to check whether the characters are encoded in big5 or not.

You may use [this tool](http://billor.chsh.chc.edu.tw/php/Tools/qBig5.php) to view the Big5 encoding of a Chinese character.

=========================== edit 2017/3/31 =============================

I found something interesting:

The Big5 encoding of `信` is `ab 48`.

```
echo 信 | out-file -filepath abc.txt -encoding Default
echo 信信 | out-file -filepath abc.txt -encoding Default
echo 信信信 | out-file -filepath abc.txt -encoding Default
echo 信信信信 | out-file -filepath abc.txt -encoding Default
```

All of the `信`s generated by the above code are `ab 48`.

However, as the length of the characters get longer than 4, the encoding of `信` becomes `e4 bf a1`, which is UTF-8 encoding.

```
echo 信信信信信 | out-file -filepath abc.txt -encoding Default   # 信 is encoded as e4 bf a1 here.
```

It seems that the final encoding of the characters depends on the length of the charcters.

Now the question becomes how to generate long big5-encoded characters with powershell.

Comment: Check out the [MSDN page for Out-File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file). I've deleted my answer as it didn't work when I tried it. You may be able to make use of the .NET class [System.Text.Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) with `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Text.Encoding`